# Using regex in an additional jQuery Validate method

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I need to create an additional method for the jQuery validate plugin, but I'm not great with regular expressions. What I need is to check if a text input is typed like `I50xxxx` OR `i50xxxx`, where `xxxx` are alphanumerics (`0000` to `9999`)

I made this :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("matricule", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^I50\d{4}$/.test(value);
}, "Entrez un matricule valide (I50xxxx)");
```

It's Ok to check the first type, but not both. Can you help me?

Comment: `(0000 to 9999)` are numerics not alphanumerics

Answer (score 2):

Add `i` modifier in order to perform a case-insensitive search.

```
/^I50\d{4}$/i.test(value);
```

or

```
/^[iI]50\d{4}$/.test(value);
```